# Viewbinding with error: incompatible with attribute android:visibility

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to set the `visibility` and the `src` of an `ImageView` using data binding.  I don't know why this error is showing up, and I truely believe that this was working at one point, but I could be wrong.

Layout:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <import type="android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat" />
    <variable
        name="viewData"
        type="com.myapp.SomethingViewData" />
</data>
    ...
        <ImageView
            ...
            android:src="@{ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, viewData.getIconResource())}"
            android:visibility="@{viewData.getIconVisibility() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
```

Data class

```
@Parcelize
data class SomethingViewData(val iconResource: Int,
                             val iconVisibility: Boolean) : Parcelable
```

Error message:

```
error: '@{ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, viewData.getIconResource())}' is incompatible with attribute android:src (attr) reference|color.   
error: '@{viewData.getIconVisibility() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}' is incompatible with attribute android:visibility (attr) enum [gone=2, invisible=1, visible=0].
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you certain that `viewData.getIconVisibility()` is a boolean?

Comment: The variable viewData type is of SomethingViewData class and the data class which you posted is GetStartedViewData. Can you confirm if the type refers to the data same data class you posted?

Comment: @Guatam, edited

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In my case a missing closing brace caused this error to pop up for me - I had:

```
android:visibility="@{moment.state == State.COMPLETE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE"
```

instead of:

```
android:visibility="@{moment.state == State.COMPLETE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
```

Comment: Thanks man, surprisingly relevant. Took me googling and clicking through to this answer to notice that missing brace :facepalm:

Comment: Android studio is dumb enough not to remind a missing brace but attribute incompatibility.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same error and solved it with help of this site: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-databinding/#2

I needed to convert my ConstraintLayout to a data binding layout like shown on this picture from this site:
[image]

Maybe this will help someone!

Comment: Thank you a lot, this was the easiest way to deal with data binding in Kotlin

Answer (score 11):

Wow, so, somehow `dataBinding { enabled = true }` was removed from my app modules build.gradle file.  Adding it back and everything worked like before.

Comment: The same happened to me.

Comment: It should now be `buildFeatures{ dataBinding true}`

Answer (score 0):

Your "getIconVisibility" return an integer but `android:visibility` (in your XML file) need a enum value: Visibility.Gone | Visibility.Visible | Visibility.Invisible

Comment: Ah yes, I've been trying that too. Changed to boolean, and did this in the layout `android:visibility="@{viewData.getIconVisibility() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"`, but i still get the error

Comment: You have the same error with "android:src". Did you resolve it?

Comment: I have not figured it out yet, no

Comment: ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, viewData.getIconResource()) -> this will help you create a drawable object but it's not used for XML file!!! In your case may be:  android:src="@{viewData.getIconResource()}"

Answer (score 0):

> Try using single quotations in your `src` and `visibility`

```
android:src='@{ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, viewData.getIconResource())}'
android:visibility='@{viewData.getIconVisibility() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}'
```

Comment: What I dont understand is that there are others that work. `android:text="@{viewData.getTitleString()}"` for example.

Comment: Single quotes didnt fix, sorry

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 I just had to use it like this:

```xml
android:visibility="gone"
```

According to the documentations the possible values for the layout XML are:

```xml
android:visibility="visible|invisible|gone"
```

You can check the documentation here: [Android View Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:visibility)