# Android controlling view visibility and i get error

Tags: android, android-databinding

in databinding of android simply i want to control view visibility by checking viewmodel parameter as `profilePicUrl`

## Solution 1:

when `profilePicUrl` is empty view should be gone, otherwise that should be visible, for example:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <import type="android.text.TextUtils"/>

    <variable name="viewModel" type="xx.xxxxx.xxxxxxx.MyViewModel"/>
</data>

...

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="@{TextUtils.isEmpty(viewModel.profilePicUrl) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
    >
```

i get this error:

```
error: '@{TextUtils.isEmpty(viewModel.profilePicUrl)? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE' is incompatible with attribute visibility (attr) enum [gone=2, invisible=1, visible=0].
```

## Solution 2:

after getting this error i try to test another solution to approach that, for example:

`BindingAdapters` class:

```
object BindingAdapters {
    @BindingAdapter("visibleIf")
    @JvmStatic
    fun changeVisibility(@NonNull imageView: ImageView, visible: Boolean) {
        if (visible) {
            imageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            imageView.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
}
```

xml layout:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <import type="android.text.TextUtils"/>

    <variable name="viewModel" type="xx.xxxxx.xxxxxxx.MyViewModel"/>
</data>

...

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:visibleIf="@{TextUtils.isEmpty(viewModel.profilePicUrl)}"
    >
```

i get this error:

```
error: attribute visibleIf (aka xxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx:visibleIf) not found.
```

Comment: @JeelVankhede yes, i'm using `androidX`

Comment: @JeelVankhede are you sure that should be import from androidX? for example: `<import type="androidx.view.View"/>`

Comment: Do you happen to be using an adapter named `android:visibility` that expects an enum anywhere?

Comment: BTW, as far as I know, `androidx.view.View` isn't a thing. I am doing data-binding with AndroidX and `<import type="android.view.View" />` works like a charm.

Comment: @JulioE.RodríguezCabañas yes you are right, i get error to import them, could you help me?

Comment: I would like to, but this error is very weird. I have the exact same code in several layouts and it always works for me. Assuming you have configured your project properly to do data-binding, all I can think of is that you might have an adapter overriding the `android:visibility` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have enabled data-binding properly? Your code is correct, so there is no reason why it shouldn't work.

Please make sure this code is added in the Gradle file of your app module:

```java
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

In addition, I would recommend adding this to the `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

Here you can see a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53221339/3891038).

Regarding the second solution, sometimes importing the object that contains the adapter methods helps:

```xml
<import type="com.your.package.name.BindingAdapters" />
```

Also, please make sure you have added this attribute on your `layout` tag:

```xml
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: `dataBinding` is enabled on my project, solution 1 work fine, yes you are right, but solution 2 doesn't work

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Kudos, it worked for me just by adding `dataBinding true`